# Como desativas as restrições cross origin pra rodar em localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cross-domain

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste - LOTECE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="resultado"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.resultado').load('http://www.lotece.com.br/v2/ .dataResultado');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tenho o código acima, porém o problema em não listar os resultados tem haver com o cross-origin. Sou iniciante em muita coisa e não sei como resolver esse problema. De início que era pra o resultado ser isso, quando acessado o localhost/Teste.html.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeceria se me ajudassem a resolver esse empasse. [sei nem por onde começar, rs]

Comment: Você está acessando seu `Teste.html` de um servidor local ou carregando o arquivo direto (`file://.../Teste.html`)? pode postar o erro do console?

Comment: Esse domínio lotece.com.br é o seu? É ele que precisa liberar o acesso, se não estiver no seu controle não tem jeito.

Comment: Se for só para testar o ajax, você deve iniciar seu chrome com o argumento: --disable-web-security  . Isso vai funcionar só para você ou para quem iniciar o chrome com isso. Se você for usar dominios diferentes quando o sistema estiver em produção(várias pessoas usando), você terá que liberar na aplicação hospedada em lotece.com.br

Comment: De início só acessei o arquivo [abri no chrome mesmo] @bfavaretto . O lotece.com.br é o domínio que quero puxar os resultados e um site externo.

Comment: @HugoLima o intuito era fazer uma aplicação que mostrasse os resultados. Não sei como fazer isso no servidor também. Os usuários acessariam e veriam os resultados de lotece.com.br.

Comment: Como bem apontado pelo @bfavaretto, a proteção CORS é do lado do servidor. Não há o que fazer. Uma sugestão é criar um script na sua aplicação (php, node...) que atuasse como proxy. Isto permitiria você acessar esta página com AJAX.

Comment: Srs @HugoLima  mrlew bfavaretto então mudo minha pergunta e perguntaria como pegar os resultados de www.lotece.com.br/v2/ e listar em uma página ? De forma simples. Att

Comment: Faça outra pergunta @CRISLANIO. Essa aqui já foi respondida.

Comment: Você não está acessando um servidor no localhost e sim em lotece.com.

Answer (score 0):

A solução era essa. Mas testando outro dia simplesmente não mostra mais nada.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Cris - LOTECE

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.resultado').load('https://crossorigin.me/http://www.lotece.com.br/v2/ .dataResultado');
    });
</script>
```

O resultado que foi gerado e no dia seguinte não mais encontrasse na imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]